Traefik. Redirections
I got two services enabled behind traefic (all are via docker).
Here compose.yml Im using for this:
Some parts are ommited
backend:
    extends:
      file: ./../backend/.docker/compose.yml
      service: backend
    networks:
      - traefik-public
      - default
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public

      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend.loadbalancer.server.port=80

      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`, `www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) && PathPrefix(`/api`, `/docs`, `/redoc`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.entrypoints=http

      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`, `www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) && PathPrefix(`/api`, `/docs`, `/redoc`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.tls.certresolver=le

      # Enable www redirection for HTTP and HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.middlewares=https-redirect,${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect

  frontend:
    extends:
      file: ./../frontend/.docker/compose.yml
      service: frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik-public
      - default
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public

      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=80

      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`, `www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.entrypoints=http

      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`, `www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.tls.certresolver=le

      # Enable www redirection for HTTP and HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.middlewares=https-redirect,${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect

      # Define Traefik Middleware to handle domain with and without "www" to redirect to only one
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^http(s)?://www.(${DOMAIN?Variable not set})/(.*)
      # Redirect a domain with www to non-www
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=http$${1}://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}/$${3}

networks:
  # Use the previously created public network "traefik-public", shared with other
  # services that need to be publicly available via this Traefik
  traefik-public:
    external: true


Here exported config via docker compose config command:
name: docker
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ...
      dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        BACKEND_HOST: 0.0.0.0
        BACKEND_HOST_PORT: "8000"
      target: prod

    container_name: backend
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_started
        required: true
      pgadmin:
        condition: service_started
        required: true
    environment:
      BACKEND_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      BACKEND_HOST_PORT: "8000"
      FIRST_SUPERUSER: admin
      FIRST_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD: ...
      POSTGRES_CONTAINER_NAME: db
      POSTGRES_DB: <...>
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ...
      POSTGRES_PORT: "5432"
      POSTGRES_SERVER: db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      PROJECT_NAME: <...>-backend
      USERS_OPEN_REGISTRATION: "True"
    labels:
      traefik.constraint-label: traefik-public
      traefik.docker.network: traefik-public
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-backend-http.entrypoints: http
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-backend-http.middlewares: https-redirect,<...>-ru-www-redirect
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-backend-http.rule: Host(`localhost`, `www.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/api`, `/docs`, `/redoc`)
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-backend-https.entrypoints: https
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-backend-https.middlewares: <...>-ru-www-redirect
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-backend-https.rule: Host(`localhost`, `www.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/api`, `/docs`, `/redoc`)
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-backend-https.tls: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-backend-https.tls.certresolver: le
      traefik.http.services.<...>-ru-backend.loadbalancer.server.port: "8000"
    networks:
      default: null
      traefik-public: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 8000
        published: "8000"
        protocol: tcp

  frontend:
    build:
      ...
    container_name: frontend-dev
    depends_on:
      ...
    environment:
      FRONTEND_HOST_PORT: "8080"
      NODE_ENV: development
      VITE_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      VITE_PORT: "5173"
    labels:
      traefik.constraint-label: traefik-public
      traefik.docker.network: traefik-public
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.middlewares.<...>-ru-www-redirect.redirectregex.regex: ^http(s)?://www.(localhost)/(.*)
      traefik.http.middlewares.<...>-ru-www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement: http$${1}://localhost/$${3}
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-frontend-http.entrypoints: http
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-frontend-http.middlewares: https-redirect,<...>-ru-www-redirect
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-frontend-http.rule: Host(`localhost`, `www.localhost`)
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-frontend-https.entrypoints: https
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-frontend-https.middlewares: <...>-ru-www-redirect
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-frontend-https.rule: Host(`localhost`, `www.localhost`)
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-frontend-https.tls: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.<...>-ru-frontend-https.tls.certresolver: le
      traefik.http.services.<...>-ru-frontend.loadbalancer.server.port: "5173"
    networks:
      default: null
      traefik-public: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 5173
        published: "5173"
        protocol: tcp
    restart: "no"

  ...

  proxy:
    command:
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label`, `traefik-public`)
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - --accesslog
      - --log
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --api
      - --api.insecure=true
    image: traefik:v2.3
    labels:
      traefik.constraint-label: traefik-public
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.contenttype.autodetect: "false"
    networks:
      default: null
      traefik-public: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 80
        published: "80"
        protocol: tcp
      - mode: ingress
        target: 8080
        published: "8090"
        protocol: tcp
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
        bind:
          create_host_path: true
networks:
    driver: bridge
  default:
    name: docker_default
  traefik-public:
    name: docker_traefik-public

Questions:
Why am I getting redirected from localhost:80 to frontend, but not to backend?
How to config properly redirections from localhost/docs to backend/docs and keep redirections to frontend?
Some new additions:
After research Ive found out that proplem is here:

this is log of proxy container
It is attempting to call backend's container with http://IP:8000
BUT
Inspect on backends container tells me that his internal docker's IP

It is trying to call it via internal network, but not via traefik-public
Also, sometimes after recriation of traefik-public network IP is matching, but this behaviour is completly random!

I traefic the same as traefik?

@mkrieger1. yes. sorry for typo

The issu was in Network order, my backend was multiple networks, traefik-public and backend-net
Traefik v2.3 sending requests to networks in asc sort. So traefik-public network MUST go first with naming
